# Sort Arraylist of Arraylist in java(finding subsets in java)

Tags: java

I wanted to find the subsets of a given integer arraylist and return it as arraylist of arraylist in sorted order in java.

for eg: for the i/p : 1 2 3

o/p:

//blank space

1

1 2

1 2 3

1 3

2

2 3

3

**and not as**

1 2 3

1 2

1 3

1

2 3

2

3

Thankyou for the help.

```
class Solution
{
    public static void subsetsRec(ArrayList<Integer> A, ArrayList<Integer> curr, int ind, ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> res) {
        if (ind == A.size()) {
            // System.out.println(curr);
            // res.add(curr);
            res.add(new ArrayList<>(curr));
            return;
        }
    
        curr.add(A.get(ind));
        subsetsRec(A, curr, ind + 1, res);
        curr.remove(curr.size() - 1);
        subsetsRec(A, curr, ind + 1, res);
    }

    public static ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> subsets(ArrayList<Integer> A) {
        ArrayList<Integer> curr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
        subsetsRec(A, curr, 0, res);
        return res;
    }
}
```

Comment: What should be the output for input 3 2 1 ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, imo, is to convert each inner list to a string and sort them in lexical order.

- stream the list of lists
- for each list, convert each digit to a string and join using a collector.
- them sort in natural order, converting to a list.

```
List<List<Integer>> list = List.of(List.of(1, 2, 3),
        List.of(1, 2), List.of(1, 3), List.of(1),
        List.of(2, 3), List.of(2), List.of(3));

List<String> result = list.stream()
        .map(lst -> lst.stream().map(i->Integer.toString(i))
                .collect(Collectors.joining(" ")))
        .sorted(Comparator.naturalOrder()).toList();

result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

prints

```
1
1 2
1 2 3
1 3
2
2 3
3
```